# Timestamp_problem?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I am creating a table using sql queries. I have two columns, namely `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`. For both timings to be entered is supposed to be after 8am and before 10pm respectively. So can you just tell me what am i supposed to do? The datatype to be used is `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add a specific tag for which database system you're using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc)

Comment: You can define a check constraint to ensure that.

Comment: The server in use is Oracle. And i did enter the CHECK constraint, but again stuck with a problem. Time format is 12 hours and not 24, So time beyond 12hours is unacceptable.

Comment: Show us your check constraint. A (real) `timestamp` does not have "a format". Neither a 12 hour nor a 24 hour format. If I had to guess, I would say you are comparing string constants to a timestamp value which is subject to the evil implicit data type conversion.

Answer (score -1):

TimeStamp/Version type column can be one in a table. You can take datetime column for this. for time calculation you can use datediff function with  h for hours d for days etc.

TimeStamp and version type column  is use only for data concurrency, you can't enter explicitly value in this column.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer most of what's asked here, and also seems to assume [tag:sql-server], which is by no means known as yet, given the lack of specific tags on the question.

Comment: please specify database which you are using.